# Query that concatenate possible NULL value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to build a query to concatenate a multipla value from database.
So this is the query:

```
SELECT FiscalCode + ' - ' + Name + ' ' + Surname + ' - ' + City + ' - '  BirthTime AS Value, FiscalCode AS OrderBy
FROM   AA_V_PHR_CCD_Person
```

FiscalCode,Name,Surname IS NOT NULL into database configuration but City and BirthTime are NULLABLE into the database configuration.

Now if City or BirthTime is NULL on the db the result of the query is NULL, I can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `coalesce` to substitute `null` with an empty string.

```
SELECT FiscalCode + ' - ' + Name + ' ' + Surname + ' - ' + COALESCE(City,'') + ' - '
COALESCE(BirthTime,'') AS Value, FiscalCode AS OrderBy
FROM AA_V_PHR_CCD_Person
```

From SQL Server versions 2012 and later, you can use [`CONCAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql) which implicitly converts `null` values to an empty string.

```
SELECT CONCAT(FiscalCode , ' - ' , Name , ' ' , Surname , ' - ' , City, ' - ', BirthTime) as Value,
FiscalCode AS OrderBy
FROM AA_V_PHR_CCD_Person
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql)

```
SELECT FiscalCode + ' - ' + Name + ' ' + Surname + ' - ' + ISNULL(City,'') + ' - '
ISNULL(BirthTime,'') AS Value, FiscalCode AS OrderBy
FROM AA_V_PHR_CCD_Person
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using ISNULL :

```
SELECT ISNULL(FiscalCode,'') + ' - ' + ISNULL(Name,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(Surname,'') + ' - ' + ISNULL(City,'') + ' - ' + ISNULL(BirthTime,'') AS Value, FiscalCode AS OrderBy FROM   AA_V_PHR_CCD_Person
```